# aws - how to calculate how many instances I need?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My app was easily deployed with OpsWorks.

Currently it has just 100 daily access in a single page with a single MySQL insertion.

```
HaProxy - 1 instance t2.micro
App     - 1 instance t2.micro
RDS     - 1 instance t2.micro
```

Tomorrow I'll get 50k access in the same minutes (facebook posting and ads).

My question is: how many instances and servers do I need to this traffic? Maybe something like:

```
HaProxy - 10 instance t2.micro
App     - 10 instance t2.micro
RDS     - 1  instance t2.large
```

Is this enought? How to know this?

Comment: The only way to know is to benchmark.  The answer is highly dependent on what the app does.  Note that .micro instances have limited network and disk IO throughput. Why do you have one proxy server per app server?  Normally a proxy server would route traffic between different app servers.  You can also use ELB for that functionality, eliminating the need to manage and scale your own proxy servers.

Comment: Try a load testing tool, measure response times. There are some simple ones like [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) or [Siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)

Comment: I wasn't unable to get ELB working with OpsWorks app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659466/aws-elastic-load-balancer-returning-timeout